# Django how to render sub-classes of an abstract model class in one view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Let's first see what do I have.

In my `models.py` I have:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class Parent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    category = models.ForiegnKey(Category, related_name="%(class)s_set")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Foo(Parent):
    foo = models.PositiveInteger(default=1)


class Bar(Parent):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Baz(Parent):
    baz = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

As you see, I have 3 model sub-classes `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` which inherit from the abstract model `Parent`.

Each unique `category` can only have one `parent_set` which is either a `foo_set`, a `bar_set`, or a `baz_set`. (Assume so far I have 3 categories with unique names as `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`).

I have the following views in my `views.py`:

```
class FooListView(ListView):  # template: foos/foo_list.html
    model = Foo


class BarListView(ListView):  # template: bars/bar_list.html
    model = Bar


class BazListView(ListView):  # template: bazs/baz_list.html
    model = Baz


def index(request):
    return render('index.html, context={"categories": Category.objects.all()})
```

and in my `urls.py` I have:

```
url_patterns = [
    path('foo/list', FooListView.as_view(), name='foo_list'),
    path('bar/list', BarListView.as_view(), name='bar_list'),
    path('baz/list', BazListView.as_view(), name='baz_list'),
]
```

Now in my `index.html` for each `category`, I want to render the `parent_set` (which is either `foo_set`, `bar_set`, or `baz_set`) related to that `category`. I do not know how can I do this elegantly.

What I don't like to do is this (which requires me to add FOO, BAR, and BAZ to context, besides the ugly conditional statements):

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.name == FOO %}
        {% include 'foos/foo_list.html' with foos=category.foo_set.all %}
    {% elif category.name == BAR %}
        {% include 'bars/bar_list.html' with bars=category.bar_set.all %}
    {% elif category.name == BAZ %}
        {% include 'bazs/baz_list.html' with bazs=category.baz_set.all %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What I like to do is something like:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    ??? somehow use the reverse_name defined in urls.py to ???
    ??? render {% url '{{ category.name }}_list' %} ???
{% endfor %}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks,

Comment: I am on the same boat atm. What did you end up using?

Comment: The ugly if statements! If you find out any workaround please let me know

Comment: {% include 'foos/foo_list.html' with foos=category.foo_set.all %}  in this line simply use string interpolation. Use that category.name variable

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join